# What is the modality of a statement that follows from a necessary statement?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, philosophy-of-logic

Let □P.

Suppose □P => Q.

What can be said about the modality of Q?

□P <=> P holds in every possible world.

Thus it is available as a premise to derive Q in every possible world.

Suppose Q is derived via axiom-based term substitution (proof), then since axioms are utilized, and they are assumed as necessary, then in every possible world, Q is derived necessarily.

Thus, either (□P => Q) => □Q or, if □P => ♢Q then some premise used to derive Q was possible, not necessary, which follows by negating the prior assumptions for deriving □Q.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary, unless you mean strict implication. Material implication is a truth-functional connective and therefore the proposition "P implies Q" speaks only of one possible world, i.e. the actual world. To get a strict implication you need "necessarily (P implies Q)" in which case indeed Q holds necessarily (given that P holds necessarily).

If we are speaking of derivation however, i.e. P |= Q, then indeed Q is necessary, given that P is necessary. The **necessitation rule** says that if X is a theorem, then (necessarily X) is also a theorem. So, given P |= Q, from deduction theorem, |= (P -> Q), or, in other words, P -> Q is a theorem. From this we get that (necessarily P -> Q) holds (and is derivable from axioms) and the reasoning proceeds as outlined above.

Answer (score 2):

> Let ☐P.
>
> Suppose ☐P => Q.
>
> What can be said about the modality of Q?

Nothing. The expression *”necessarily P implies Q”* says everything there is to be said.

There are multiple modal logics. They start with different formation rules. Some modal logics start with the rule “*if necessarily p is a theorem, then so is p*”. But a modal logic can also choose to reject such a formation rule. For this reason one cannot draw further inferences without providing the complete formation rules of the logic these theorems occur in. For example, you could have a modal logic in which *”if necessarily P implies Q is a theorem, then so is necessarily Q”*. But that’s just a matter of furnishing it with that axiom.

---

> ☐P <=> P holds in every possible world.

We can supply a semantics to these symbols, these modal operators, using the possible worlds convention. However, be careful to distinguish between the implication arrow, “P -> necessarily P”, and the idea of a formation rule (“if P is a theorem, then necessarily P is a theorem”). The former is not a formation rule - the implication arrow is a logical symbol in our logical language, similar to the conjunction, disjunction, and negation symbols. We cannot derive any conclusions from it unless our logic supplies formation rules regarding what can be done, with any such statement. For example, the rule typically known as “modus ponens” says “if p is a theorem, and p -> q is a theorem, then q is a theorem”.

Thus, it is not given that if P is a theorem, then so is necessarily P. That would require you to state that as a formation rule of your logic.

Since you wanted to interpret this using some sort of possible worlds model, consider how that formation rule would be reflected in a possible worlds structure. If “if P, then necessarily P” is true in a logic, then it means that for any theorem in any world, that theorem must be true in all worlds. That means that all worlds are identical; and that there is only one unique “possible world” up to identity.

However, like formation rules, we are also at liberty to use different “possible worlds” structures and models. For example, [accessibility relations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessibility_relation) add more structure to a possible worlds model, by introducing the idea that some worlds are not aware of the truths in other worlds. If we used accessibility relations, then “if P then necessarily P” no longer implies the existence of only one unique world (a singleton universe) - but it implies that *locally*; so, it holds for all worlds *accessible* to each world (a discrete universe). What this would mean is that this universe is a multiverse of “isolated worlds”: there may be an infinitude of worlds, but none of them can access any world but themself; so each conceives of itself as the only possible world, since they don’t know of worlds where, say, P is not true.

You can make possible worlds models have more rules with other variations too. What if you could model “impossible worlds” in your model of all worlds, too?

Comment: To make your point about accessibility relations more concrete, the axiom □P ↔ P corresponds to the frame condition in which every possible world is accessible to itself but no other world is accessible to it. Hughes and Cresswell call this system Triv.

Comment: Yes and yes; thank you.